# MS-DOS Application to play .mod files

Tags: media-player, dos

I'm searching for MS-DOS Application with sources that will have functions to load the .mod file to memory and then play it.

Comment: XTC Play? http://www.cubic.org/player/index.html See also https://www.opus.co.tt/dave/sound.htm

Comment: Are you **really** looking for "MS-DOS" application? Or are you talking about a command line program for Windows? (Those are two very different things)

Comment: MS-DOS application